# error ': Expected input to be images (as Numpy array) following the data format convention "channels_first"' in Keras image example

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I run into the following error when I run a keras example script:

```
C:\Users\johnd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py:653: UserWarning: Expected input to be images (as Numpy array) following the data format convention "channels_first" (channels on axis 1), i.e. expected either 1, 3 or 4 channels on axis 1. However, it was passed an array with shape (60000, 1, 28, 28) (1 channels).
  ' (' + str(x.shape[self.channel_axis]) + ' channels).')
```

Here is my script:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# reshape to be [samples][pixels][width][height]
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
# convert from int to float
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
# define data preparation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(zca_whitening=True)
# fit parameters from data
datagen.fit(X_train)
# configure batch size and retrieve one batch of images
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=9):
    # create a grid of 3x3 images
    for i in range(0, 9):
        pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
        pyplot.imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))
    # show the plot
    pyplot.show()
    break
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your backend (Tensorflow/Theano) and Keras version?

Comment: Indeed, it is a bug fixed in the latest master - see update in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error but a **warning** - and I guess you have omitted to mention that the rest of the code runs ok; here is what I get after running your script:

[image]

with a `X_train.shape` of `(60000, 1, 28, 28)` and a similar warning:

```
/var/venv/tsats/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py:648: 
UserWarning: Expected input to be images (as Numpy array) following the data format 
convention "channels_first" (channels on axis 1), i.e. expected either 1, 3 or 4 channels on 
axis 1. However, it was passed an array with shape (60000, 1, 28, 28) (1 channels).    ' (' + str(x.shape[self.channel_axis]) + ' channels).')
```

Close inspection of the warning reveals that it is nonsensical: it asks that the channels be on axis 1 (they are) and that they have a value in `{1, 3, 4}` (they have a valid value of 1 indeed). Obviously it is a Keras bug - I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/7435) - but it does not affect the rest of the code and the results.

**UPDATE**: According to a [response](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/7435#issuecomment-318673240) in Keras Github issues, this is now fixed in master (haven't tested myself yet though).